# Does generic dictionary class have a method to get keys by index?

Tags: delphi, dictionary

this might be a realy easy question but i think i am mentaly blind or something; How can i get a key by its index in The Dictionary class In Delphi (10.1). I mean the structure has a property called Count, so it must have a some sort of array or a list in it, why cant i get the keys by indices.

I also tried KeyCollection property in Dictionary class, but it also doesn't have anything useful. I need something like:

```
key: string;
key := dicTest.GetKey(keyIndex);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to access the dictionary using an index?

Answer (score 7):

The Delphi RTL generic dictionary is unordered. As a consequence of being unordered, items in the container do not possess a meaningful index.

The keys can be enumerated using the `Keys` property:

```
var
  dict: TDictionary<string, Integer>;
  key: string;
....
for key in dict.Keys do
  Writeln(key);
```

Likewise the values can be enumerated using the `Values` property.

```
var
  dict: TDictionary<string, Integer>;
  value: Integer;
....
for value in dict.Values do
  Writeln(value);
```

If you wish to enumerate key/value pairs then the dictionary itself provides an enumerator for that:

```
var
  dict: TDictionary<string, Integer>;
  item: TPair<string, Integer>;
....
for item in dict do
  Writeln(item.Key, ', ', item.Value);
```

Note that for each of these enumerators, no guarantees are made about the order of the items. Simple acts like adding a new item to the dictionary can result in a change in the order of the items under enumeration.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that it is possible to access Keys, Values and the Key/Value pairs with `ToArray` as an array of appropriate type?

Comment: @nil I thought about that, but it's really just the illusion of an index. The implementation simply iterates of the dictionary using the `for item in dict` enumerator and populates an array. You may as well just use the enumerator in almost all cases.

Comment: Excellent point, but the array can be sorted, if that is desired, while that is not possible for the enumerations in the dictionary, if I'm not mistaken.But reading the question again I guess that is not really asked for.

Answer (score 4):

To add to David's answer, the whole point of a dictionary or hash-table structure is to very efficiently store and retrieve key-value pairs in memory.

This is achieved as follows:

- Items are placed into a predictable location within in large block of memory based on the key.
- When trying to find the item, you know where it *should be* stored (***based on the key***), and can immediately go to that location to hopefully find it.

The following diagram illustrates:

```
        +-------------+
        |  ..         |
        |  ..         |
Add     |World (Data) |   Find
Hello   |Abc   (Data) |   Hello
  |     |  ..         |     |
  |     |  ..         |     |
  +---> |Hello (Data) | <---+
        |  ..         |
        |  ..         |
        |Xyz   (Data) |
        +-------------+
```

Note the following:

- There is no ordering as to where items will be inserted.
- The basic operations *require* knowing the key to look them up.
- Although Delphi allows the items to be iterated, their positions are not guaranteed to be consistent.
- The big advantage of this kind of structure is that it doesn't matter how large the collection grows, adding and looking up and deleting items has the same performance. This is referred to as having *order of complexity* O(1).
- These structures tend to be inefficient in terms of memory requirements. You may have noted the "gaps" in the allocated memory in the illustration above.
- There's no built in mechanism for knowing the number of items in the collection, but it's trivial track the number as items are added/removed in a single extra field. (Which is what Delphi's implementation does.) *Knowing count does not imply you can access items by index.*

#### In summary

If you're unable to keep track of your keys, then a `Dictionary` is not the right tool for you. You may be better with a `List` or `array`. Though I suggest you make an effort to understand the benefits and limitations of these structures to help decide which is the *best tool for the job*.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to access the keys by index is to retrieve them as an array. The `Keys` property provides a function for that: `ToArray`